# Can ISP see data downloaded from Telegram?

Tags: iphone, isp, cache

When Telegram downloads files to internal storage cache, does the ISP see the data that was downloaded? Or can they not see that at all or due to encryption?

Comment: https://telegram.org/faq#q-so-how-do-you-encrypt-data Most apps will use TLS encryption so that the ISP can't see data. However, Telegram adds even more encryption.